# Doctrine Compile Error: A void function must not return a value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using PHP 7.2 and I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  A void function must not return a value
Compile Error: A void function must not return a value
```

This occurs because it looks like the doctrine/common does not support return :void.  I've got the following in my composer.json file:

```
    "php": "7.2.*",
    "symfony/symfony": "~3.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.5",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
```

But it looks like this issue that was first reported back in Jan 2017 as seen here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6221 is still not fixed.  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: well from the issue you provided they said you need `composer require doctrine/common "2.7.1 as 2.6.99"`

Comment: Does that mean that doctrine/orm is no longer supported?

Comment: no, just add "doctrine/common" : "2.9.0" 
and this should fix your issue

Comment: if you take a look here https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm the orm library it says it requires doctrine/common; thus it wont work without it or as in your case it will make some errors

Comment: Hmm, I added that, but sadly still get the same error. (cache was deleted, and "composer install" was run)

Comment: try to remove your vendors folder along with your cache and then composer install and please put docrine/common before doctrine/orm

Comment: I ran "rm -rf vendor/*" and "rm -rf var/cache/prod/*" and made sure "doctrine/common" : "2.9.0", appears before "doctrine/orm": "dev-master", in  composer.json but still got the same issue.  very strange this.

Comment: When exactly does the compile error/exception occur? Does it occur during cache warmup or afterwards when you access a page? Does manual cache warming work with the `bin/console cache:warmup` command?

Comment: bin/console cache:warmup works fine.  Only when I run some of my code (that requires a file built by doctrine) does it fail.  It breaks here: https://pastebin.com/vQxeV0gy

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was to simply use "@stable" in my composer file.

```
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "@stable",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "@stable",
    "doctrine/migrations": "@stable",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "@stable",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "@stable",
```